# clear command of SQL*Plus has no feedback when executed in a script

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

When executed interactively, we can see `xxxx cleared` from `clear` command.

```
SQL> clear column
columns cleared
SQL>
```

But if I have `clear columns` in a script and run it, I can not see any feedback from `clear` command. Why ?

```
bash-4.1$ cat simple.sql
scott/tiger
sho user
clear columns
clear computes
clear breaks
clear sql
exit
bash-4.1$ sqlplus -x @simple
USER is "SCOTT"
```

Comment: Why should sqlplus create such noise when not used interactively?

Answer (score 0):

It's not an exact anwer and I don't know why it doesn't show the output, however you can get around it by doing something like this:

```
$ cat simple.sql
LOG=scott.log
ora=`sqlplus scott/tiger <<EOF
    SPOOL $LOG APPEND
sho user
clear columns
    QUIT
EOF`|tee -a "$LOG"
$ ./simple.sql
$ cat scott.log
SQL> sho user
USER is "SCOTT"
SQL> clear columns
columns cleared
SQL>     QUIT
```